# react native - app crashes when goes in background (no error in log)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a list of audio items in a FlatList and I'm using [react-native-audio-toolkit](https://github.com/futurice/react-native-audio-toolkit) to play them. I have an instance of the Player in the child component. For some reason, when I minimizes the app, the app crashes without any error in the `react-native log-android`.

I'm not sure how to debug this. Is there a way find the cause of this error? I'm not sure which command to use `--stacktrace` with, if I could.

Also, I'm pretty sure it's due the Player in `react-native-audio-toolkit` because this error only started to come when I added it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error log wasn't displaying in react because it was an android bug and for some reason didn't display the error in react. Just run your app, open **Android Studio's Android Debugger** and perform the steps that leads to app crash and you'll see the log now.

**NOTE:** This is only if something's wrong with your android app and react native OR `react-native log-android` doesn't give you a log for the error.